# How can i display post with 30 words only in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show posts in my home page of my theme where i want to restrict the post content to be displayed as only 20 words. I can use get_content to get the content value but how can i restrict it to show only 20 words. Is there something i can do in my theme to have this restriction on displaying only in the home page

Thanks
Prady

Comment: You might also want to look at the_excerpt : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: using wordpress source code, maybe u can refer to wordpress documentation for this matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want to do is conditionally use excerpts. First you have to edit the excerpt length, Add this to your functions.php file:

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
return 20;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

If you want to change the text that it appends on the end, or remove it add this directly under the above:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return ''; // this will remove it, '...' is pretty common to signify more content though.
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

Then, if your homepage is your blog page, add the following to index.php, otherwise add it to page.php or which ever template you're using for the page in question, instead of `<?php the_content(); ?>`:

```
<?php if (is_page('home')) { the_excerpt(); } else { the_content(); } ?>
```

This should do the trick and uses WordPress's built-it functionality.

I suggest trawling the WordPress codex, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page), it's full of helpful goodies in regards to content manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [str_word_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function

Comment: Thanks... i read there we need to set the priority correctly here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length#Examples. Can you let me know where i need to set the priority? Thanks

Comment: You need use this function on your theme, in place where you show your post content(get_content function)