# How can I display nothing less than 400 words on my single post php WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Hello I would to reduce post words I only want to display nothing less than 500 word on my single page post 
Please how can I do this on WordPress

Comment: Maybe it will  helpful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550143/how-can-i-display-post-with-30-words-only-in-wordpress?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

put in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'stack_in_my_heart_the_content' );
function stack_in_my_heart_the_content($content){
    $words = explode(" ",$content);
    $content = implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,400));
    return $content;
}
```